# Django filter based on ForeignKey model field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to eliminate a field of the Barcode model that is redundant. `mostrecentscantime` of Barcode is not needed because I can reference `mostrecentscan.time`.

```
class Scan(models.Model):
    time=DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    barcode=ForeignKey('Barcode',on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='scans')
    location=ForeignKey(Location,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
class Barcode(models.Model):
    barcode = CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    time_created = DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    mostrecentscan=ForeignKey(Scan,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='+',null=True)
    mostrecentscantime=DateTimeField()
```

The problem with eliminating `mostrecentscantime` arises with this query where I am trying to determine all Barcode objects where the `time_created` and the `time` of the `mostrecentscan` is greater than 7 days.

Working Query:

```
barcodematches = Barcode.objects.annotate(
    diff=ExpressionWrapper(F('mostrecentscantime') - F('time_created'), output_field=DurationField())
    ).filter(diff__gte=timedelta(days=7))
```

I cannot simply reference `mostrecentscan.time` in this context. I have also tried adding an @property field to Barcode which doesn't work either.

Comment: `F('mostrecentscan__time')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`F`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model) expressions can follow relations in this case so this should work:

```
F('mostrecentscan__time') - F('time_created')
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, and now I understand how to use F expressions in this context. Thanks so much!